# Django - Filter related objects by through field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, through='relationships.Relationship', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers')


class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=RelationshipStatus.ACCEPTED.value, choices=[(state.value, state.name) for state in RelationshipStatus])


class RelationshipStatus(Enum):
    ACCEPTED = 'accepted'
    PENDING = 'pending'
    REJECTED = 'rejected'
```

I would like to get the followers of a given user, but only the ones that have an approved relationship.

This is easy with the following query.

```
Relationship.objects.filter(to_user=a_user, status=RelationshipStatus.ACCEPTED.value)
```

But my question is, how can I do it by using the `followers` attribute of my user?

If I do `a_user.followers.all()` I get them all, but I only want the ones with an accepted relationship.

Those won't work

`a_user.followers.filter(status=RelationshipStatus.ACCEPTED.value)` or `a_user.followers.filter(relationship__status=RelationshipStatus.ACCEPTED.value)`

since the following exception are raised

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'relationship' into field.
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
a_user.followers.filter(to_user__status=RelationshipStatus.ACCEPTED.value)
```

since you have specified `related_name='to_user'` for field `to_user`. However, maybe a name that indicating the 'Relationship` is more suitable or you may be confused of it.

Comment: doing `a_user.followers.filter(from_user__status=RelationshipStatus.ACCEPTED.value)`did the trick. Thanks!